# Looking for an old anime series featuring a spaceship as well as an underwater base

Tags: story-identification, anime, spaceship, underwater

I'm looking for an old anime series (or movie) produced in the 80's or earlier that aired fully dubbed in German TV some time before the 90's.

Most remarkable scenes I remember:

- The film starts on (most likely) Earth with some kind of coastal underwater base. It consisted of at least one, possibly more domes with an elevator and/or observation deck built into a cliff. Protagonists can be seen under clear sky on top cliffs at the coast with waves below them, so it wasn't just some kind of space station or night sky.
- At some point the protagonists start on an interplanetary journey for some reason, where it's revealed (or at least somewhat implied) that the aforementioned elevator/observation section is actually the elevated back part of the spaceship they're using. I don't think it was battleship shaped (see below).
- Before the episode's ends they arrive on some different planet, potentially meeting a blonde female.
- I think the protagonists did have differently colored uniforms not unlike those from the Yamato series.
- The story didn't have a conclusion and I don't remember the recording being cut in the middle, so it was most likely a single anime episode rather than some OVA or feature movie.

While parts of this sound very reminiscent of some *Space Battleship Yamato/Starblazer* episodes, I couldn't find any early episode that at least somewhat matched my memories (mostly lacking the underwater base). The drawing style of characters (wild range of proportions etc.) certainly matched. Or is there a chance I really just checked the wrong episodes or series?

Comment: Because of the similar Starblazers/Yamato vibe, does [Blue Noah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Carrier_Blue_Noah) ring any bells?

Comment: @McTroopers Unfortunately, no, but after skipping through the first few episodes, I can totally see why you suggested it. To be a bit more specific: the "coastal base" I referred to, would directly sit inside a cliff, it wasn't a flat island.